# Accessing namespace Within XML to parse the correct data PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, xml, laravel, xml-parsing

I'm currently trying to parse some sweet sweet XML, only to realise that i have no idea how to access the namespacing, i need to parse the English.

is anyone so kind a to help a brother out x

link to xml = https://xml.inmobalia.com/361/e55d03759a1004da29b3e364faaff2e1.xml

for example

```
<property>
    <descriptions>
        <property_desc lang="en">
        </property_desc>  
        <property_desc lang="es">
        </property_desc>  
    </descriptions>
</property>
```

PHP - here what I've tried

```
foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
    $filterd[$key]['main_advert_1'] = json_encode([
        "main_advert" => (isset($val['descriptions']['long_description']['en'])
            and !empty($val['descriptions']['long_description']['en'])
        )
        ? $val['descriptions']['long_description']['en'] : "N.A"]);
}
```

Comment: First - there're no namespacing here. Second - format your code, it is unreadable when in one line.

Comment: sorry!, i may have my terms muddled up here! i need to just pull the English description

Comment: The tag `property_desc` does not exist in that XML! Are we to ignore that portion of pseudo xml and focus upon the tags used in the php?

Comment: Yes Please, Also the link to the xml is provided about :)

Answer (score 0):

No idea whether Laravel has it's own methods for dealing with XML but using the vanilla `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath` in PHP it is a simple task to extract the desired items.

The below loads a locally saved copy of the XML data - but you could use the url instead in the call `$dom->load( $url )` etc

```
<?php
    $file='c:/wwwroot/files/xml/e55d03759a1004da29b3e364faaff2e1.xml';
    define('br','<br />');

    libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
    $dom=new DOMDocument;
    $dom->validateOnParse=false;
    $dom->recover=true;
    $dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
    $dom->load( $file );
    libxml_clear_errors();


    $xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
    $col=$xp->query('//descriptions/long_description[@lang="en"]');

    if( $col->length > 0 ){
        foreach( $col as $node )echo $node->tagName . ' ' .$node->nodeValue . br;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be:

```php
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file('https://xml.inmobalia.com/361/e55d03759a1004da29b3e364faaff2e1.xml')->children();
foreach ($xml->xpath('/properties/property') as $property) {
    echo '<h2>'.$property->reference->__toString().'</h2>';
    foreach ($property->xpath('descriptions/long_description[@lang="en"]') as $property) {
        echo $property->__toString();
    }
}
```

With this solution, you can access the other details of a property as well.

Answer (score 0):

I built an API that consumes and serves up XML, so I know how much of a joy it is to use XML in PHP. */s*

I created a package that has special support for Laravel to convert XML into a regular PHP array. It's really easy to use and comes with a globally accessible helper if that's your thing. https://github.com/mtownsend5512/xml-to-array

It it will give you easy access to the namespace information as an array key `@attributes`. So, for example to get the very first long description language you could do this:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('https://xml.inmobalia.com/361/e55d03759a1004da29b3e364faaff2e1.xml');
$result = xml_to_array($xml);
dd($result['property'][0]['descriptions']['long_description']);
```

And you'll see `@content` and `@attributes`. You can just loop over the converted XML as it is a plain PHP array.